# Android Studio: Compare existing string with TextField.text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to compare two strings in android studio. I have a *textfield* and want to compare this string with a given string.

For a better discription I added a picture. 
My existing string is for example "A", I want to check now, if the textbox contains this value, by pressing the button.

I tried this but there is a mistake in the code, that I don't find...

```
    final TextField textField = (TextField) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final String text1 = textField.getText().toString();
    final String text2 = "A";


    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("Button2", "click");
            if(text1.contains(text2)){
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I hope, that this improves my first (bad) question!

Comment: Mh... What are you trying to achieve?... I mean... when should the toast show up?

Comment: If you wanted to compare two string you should use equals(String) method

Comment: are you try to match the whole string or just part of the string clarify?

Comment: What do you mean by compare, do you mean equality ? you are using contains which checks the existence of text2 inside text1. Please be more specific about the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final String text1 = editText.getText().toString();
    final String text2 = "A";


    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("Button2", "click");
            if(text1.equals(text2)){
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you declared your `Button2` as you did with the `EditText`, going on...

You want to check if the String you have provided and the String is being written at the `EditText` is the same when you press a button, your code is right but you need to compare the value of the `EditText` dynamically, so you must change this:

```
            if(text1.contains(text2)){
            toast.show();
        }
```

To this:

```
            if(editText.getText().toString().equals(text2)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your message/Your String",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Hope this helps a little :)

Answer (score 0):

Method contain only check the `text1` contain `text2` or not. You should use `equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final String text1 = editText.getText().toString();
    final String text2 = "A";



 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("Button2", "click");
            System.out.println("text1: " + text1);
            System.out.println("text2: " + text2);
            if (text1.length()>0&&!text1.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                if(text1.equalsIgnoreCase(text2)){
                    toast.show();
                }   
            } else {
                System.out.println("text1 is null " );
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
if (text1.equals(text2)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Equal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to youse something like this because when you compare the text you must have an updated version of text1.

If you ask the text at the beginning it is nothing inside.
You have to ask the text1 at every OnClick event.

```
public OnClick(View v){

   text1 = editText.getText().toString();
   if(text1.equals(text2)){
          //doStufg
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the good and helpful answers!
I have even tried some way and it works well so far.
Thanks to everyone here. Good Work!

// editText.getText().toString().contains("A");